# How to protect Helix Perforce/p4 to not allow create new users?

Tags: windows-10, perforce

I have an installed P4-server for Windows 10 for personally usage.
Now I want to include my friend to my project and want to let my p4 server be visible to the public internet.

Now everyone is allowed to create new users, they just need the ip and port to access to create new users and get access to all files..

Is it possible to disable the "New..." in the p4 "Open Connection" dialog?

[image]

Comment: Note, dummy ip and port on the picture

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I do not recommend making your Perforce server available to the public Internet.  You should use a VPN to provide a layer of security in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods, both of which can only be done by an admin (`super` user).

1. Set up your protection table to ensure that only explicitly named users have permission to run any command that would entail user creation. This is easily done by replacing any `user *` lines in `p4 protect` with `group *` and making sure that all existing users are in a group.
2. Set [`dm.user.noautocreate`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/configurables.alphabetical.html#dm.user.noautocreate) to `2` so that users can only be created by a superuser.

I prefer (1) because it potentially allows you to delegate user creation to (non-admin) group owners, but (2) is sometimes preferred by admins who have a wide-open protection table and don't want to have to think about managing it at all.